# Office iFilter and Embedded Documents

Tags: indexing, filter

Does office iFilter (offfilt.dll) support extracting content from embedded documents i.e. Excel Spreadsheet or PowerPoint in Word?  If not, do you know if other iFilters do?

Thanks,
Kesha

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you apply the Search Links Flag to the IFilter when initializing it.

IFILTER_INIT iflags = IFILTER_INIT.SEARCH_LINKS;